# Java Swing: Transparent PNG permanently captures original background

Tags: java, swing

I have the following code:

```
import javax.swing.JWindow;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

public class sutff extends JWindow
{
    //Get transparent image that will be use as splash screen image.
    Image bi=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("window.png");
    ImageIcon ii=new ImageIcon(bi);
    public sutff()
    {
        try
        {
            setSize(ii.getIconWidth(),ii.getIconHeight());
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            show();
            //Thread.sleep(10000);
            //dispose();
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"This program will exit !!!","<>",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //Paint transparent image onto JWindow
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage(bi,0,0,this);
    }
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        sutff tss=new sutff();
    }
}
```

The purpose is to create a window that is translucent and resembles Windows Aero-style glass. I have the following transparent png that I am using:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IoTk.png

The problem is that since its transparent, its suppose to show the things behind the window, right? That's what it does when first executed, except whatever window is behind this "transparent window" when it first starts up, the program somehow creates an "image" of that and permanently attaches it with the window. So even if I minimize the windows behind this "transparent window," the image of the first background window remains.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

When I took this screen shot, I had already minimized the command prompt and the IDE which can be seen in the background, yet it still remains in the background of the window.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Don't override the paint() method of a top level container, especially when you don't invoke super.paint(). This will cause painting problems. If you ever do need to do custom painting then you should override the paintComponent() method of JPanel (or JComponent) and then add the panel to the window/frame. Read the Swing tutorial on Custom Painting. This advice is given daily, I don't know why people still try to override paint()???

However this is only one of your problems. The better solution is to add your image to a JLabel and then add the label to the window. You will also need to make the window background transparent:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

public class Stuff extends JWindow
{
    //Get transparent image that will be use as splash screen image.
    Image bi=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("transparent.png");
    ImageIcon ii=new ImageIcon(bi);
    public Stuff()
    {
        try
        {
            setBackground( new Color(0, 0, 0, 0) );
            setSize(ii.getIconWidth(),ii.getIconHeight());
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            JLabel label = new JLabel(ii);
            add(label);
            show();
            //Thread.sleep(10000);
            //dispose();
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"This program will exit !!!","<>",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

/*
    //Paint transparent image onto JWindow
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawImage(bi,0,0,this);
    }
*/
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Stuff tss=new Stuff();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, you window is actually transparent.  Java still thinks that the Window opaque and therefore won't update the graphics in such away as to show what's actually behind.

Creating a transparent window is relatively simple in Java since Java 1.6.10 (I think)

The following is a very simple example, using a semi transparent paint effect that will allow what ever falls below the window to continue to be painted correctly.

```
import com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TransaprentBlur {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TransaprentBlur();
    }

    public TransaprentBlur() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
//                Java 6...
//                AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(frame, true);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.setSize(400, 400);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setOpaque(false);

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Shape shape = new RoundRectangle2D.Float(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1, 20, 20);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(new Color(225, 225, 225, 128));
            g2d.fill(shape);
            g2d.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g2d.draw(shape);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

**Update with image example**

Screen shoots showing windows been moved behind the window...

[image][image]

Basically, all you need to do, is place you image rendering code with in the `paintComponent` method of `TestPane`

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TransaprentBlur {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TransaprentBlur();
    }

    public TransaprentBlur() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
//                Java 6...
//                AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(frame, true);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.setSize(400, 400);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage image;

        public TestPane() {

            try {
                image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/5UNGbsr.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
            setOpaque(false);

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return image == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (image != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                int x = (getWidth() - image.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - image.getHeight()) / 2;
                g2d.drawImage(image, x, y, this);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: That helps me get the conceptual part of it, but how would I incorporate the transparent png with this?

Comment: @DemCodeLines, what don't you understand??? I gave you working code that used your transparent png image. What more of an explanation do you require? Are you confused because I called the image "transparent" instead of "window"?

Comment: @DemCodeLines Pretty much what you were doing before, but with this code as a bases.  Take you image rendering code and place it within the `paintComponent` method, simple...

Comment: -1 for the second example of using an image for "reinventing the wheel". A JLabel already displays an image at its preferred size and is non-opaque by default.

Comment: @camickr And if the next thing the OP wants to do is add components to it, then Kleo would kick my butt for suggesting to a user to layout components on label. There isn't sufficient context to suggest that either approach is correct, although I do agree that a `JLabel` would do the same job just as well. In this case I can't win

Comment: Then that is a different question and (potentially) a different answer. This question was about displaying an transparent image in a transparent window. So the keys to the answer are to make sure the background of the window is transparent and to paint an image. The easiest way to paint an image at its preferred size is to use a JLabel. People should not be given the impression that you must do custom painting to display an image. We already answer too many custom painting questions. Lets encourage people to explore the power of the existing Swing components.