# Overrode Paint method, can't add any control to window

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, transparency

I have the following code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImageOp;
import java.awt.image.ConvolveOp;
import java.awt.image.Kernel;

import java.awt.image.ColorModel;
import java.awt.image.Raster;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.Transparency;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import java.io.IOException;

public class sutff extends JWindow
{
    private BufferedImage bi;

    public sutff() {
        try {
            bi = GraphicsUtilities.loadCompatibleImage(getClass().getResource("window1.png"));
            setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,1));
            setSize(bi.getWidth(),bi.getHeight());
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            show();

            JPanel j = new JPanel();
            j.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            j.setSize(20,20);
            add(j);
            j.setVisible(true);
            repaint();
            revalidate();
        }
        catch(Exception exception) { exception.printStackTrace(); }
    }

    //Paint transparent image onto JWindow
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        bi = getGaussianBlurFilter(4,true).filter(bi,null);
        g.drawImage(bi,0,0,null);
    }

    public static ConvolveOp getGaussianBlurFilter(int radius,
            boolean horizontal) {
        if (radius < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Radius must be >= 1");
        }

        int size = radius * 2 + 1;
        float[] data = new float[size];

        float sigma = radius / 3.0f;
        float twoSigmaSquare = 2.0f * sigma * sigma;
        float sigmaRoot = (float) Math.sqrt(twoSigmaSquare * Math.PI);
        float total = 0.0f;

        for (int i = -radius; i <= radius; i++) {
            float distance = i * i;
            int index = i + radius;
            data[index] = (float) Math.exp(-distance / twoSigmaSquare) / sigmaRoot;
            total += data[index];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data[i] /= total;
        }

        Kernel kernel = null;
        if (horizontal) {
            kernel = new Kernel(size, 1, data);
        } else {
            kernel = new Kernel(1, size, data);
        }
        return new ConvolveOp(kernel, ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP, null);
    }
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        sutff tss=new sutff();
    }
}

/**
 * <p><code>GraphicsUtilities</code> contains a set of tools to perform
 * common graphics operations easily. These operations are divided into
 * several themes, listed below.</p>
 * <h2>Compatible Images</h2>
 * <p>Compatible images can, and should, be used to increase drawing
 * performance. This class provides a number of methods to load compatible
 * images directly from files or to convert existing images to compatibles
 * images.</p>
 * <h2>Creating Thumbnails</h2>
 * <p>This class provides a number of methods to easily scale down images.
 * Some of these methods offer a trade-off between speed and result quality and
 * shouuld be used all the time. They also offer the advantage of producing
 * compatible images, thus automatically resulting into better runtime
 * performance.</p>
 * <p>All these methodes are both faster than
 * {@link java.awt.Image#getScaledInstance(int, int, int)} and produce
 * better-looking results than the various <code>drawImage()</code> methods
 * in {@link java.awt.Graphics}, which can be used for image scaling.</p>
 * <h2>Image Manipulation</h2>
 * <p>This class provides two methods to get and set pixels in a buffered image.
 * These methods try to avoid unmanaging the image in order to keep good
 * performance.</p>
 *
 * @author Romain Guy <romain.guy@mac.com>
 */
class GraphicsUtilities {
    private GraphicsUtilities() {
    }

    // Returns the graphics configuration for the primary screen
    private static GraphicsConfiguration getGraphicsConfiguration() {
        return GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().
                    getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
    }

    /**
     * <p>Returns a new <code>BufferedImage</code> using the same color model
     * as the image passed as a parameter. The returned image is only compatible
     * with the image passed as a parameter. This does not mean the returned
     * image is compatible with the hardware.</p>
     *
     * @param image the reference image from which the color model of the new
     *   image is obtained
     * @return a new <code>BufferedImage</code>, compatible with the color model
     *   of <code>image</code>
     */
    public static BufferedImage createColorModelCompatibleImage(BufferedImage image) {
        ColorModel cm = image.getColorModel();
        return new BufferedImage(cm,
            cm.createCompatibleWritableRaster(image.getWidth(),
                                              image.getHeight()),
            cm.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
    }

    /**
     * <p>Returns a new compatible image with the same width, height and
     * transparency as the image specified as a parameter.</p>
     *
     * @see java.awt.Transparency
     * @see #createCompatibleImage(int, int)
     * @see #createCompatibleImage(java.awt.image.BufferedImage, int, int)
     * @see #createCompatibleTranslucentImage(int, int)
     * @see #loadCompatibleImage(java.net.URL)
     * @see #toCompatibleImage(java.awt.image.BufferedImage)
     * @param image the reference image from which the dimension and the
     *   transparency of the new image are obtained
     * @return a new compatible <code>BufferedImage</code> with the same
     *   dimension and transparency as <code>image</code>
     */
    public static BufferedImage createCompatibleImage(BufferedImage image) {
        return createCompatibleImage(image, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    }

    /**
     * <p>Returns a new compatible image of the specified width and height, and
     * the same transparency setting as the image specified as a parameter.</p>
     *
     * @see java.awt.Transparency
     * @see #createCompatibleImage(java.awt.image.BufferedImage)
     * @see #createCompatibleImage(int, int)
     * @see #createCompatibleTranslucentImage(int, int)
     * @see #loadCompatibleImage(java.net.URL)
     * @see #toCompatibleImage(java.awt.image.BufferedImage)
     * @param width the width of the new image
     * @param height the height of the new image
     * @param image the reference image from which the transparency of the new
     *   image is obtained
     * @return a new compatible <code>BufferedImage</code> with the same
     *   transparency as <code>image</code> and the specified dimension
     */
    public static BufferedImage createCompatibleImage(BufferedImage image,
                                                      int width, int height) {
        return getGraphicsConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(width, height,
                                                   image.getTransparency());
    }

    /**
     * <p>Returns a new opaque compatible image of the specified width and
     * height.</p>
     *
     * @see #createCompatibleImage(java.awt.image.BufferedImage)
     * @see #createCompatibleImage(java.awt.image.BufferedImage, int, int)
     * @see #createCompatibleTranslucentImage(int, int)
     * @see #loadCompatibleImage(java.net.URL)
     * @see #toCompatibleImage(java.awt.image.BufferedImage)
     * @param width the width of the new image
     * @param height the height of the new image
     * @return a new opaque compatible <code>BufferedImage</code> of the
     *   specified width and height
     */
    public static BufferedImage createCompatibleImage(int width, int height) {
        return getGraphicsConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(width, height);
    }

    /**
     * <p>Returns a new translucent compatible image of the specified width
     * and height.</p>
     *
     * @see #createCompatibleImage(java.awt.image.BufferedImage)
     * @see #createCompatibleImage(java.awt.image.BufferedImage, int, int)
     * @see #createCompatibleImage(int, int)
     * @see #loadCompatibleImage(java.net.URL)
     * @see #toCompatibleImage(java.awt.image.BufferedImage)
     * @param width the width of the new image
     * @param height the height of the new image
     * @return a new translucent compatible <code>BufferedImage</code> of the
     *   specified width and height
     */
    public static BufferedImage createCompatibleTranslucentImage(int width,
                                                                 int height) {
        return getGraphicsConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(width, height,
                                                   Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
    }

    /**
     * <p>Returns a new compatible image from a URL. The image is loaded from the
     * specified location and then turned, if necessary into a compatible
     * image.</p>
     *
     * @see #createCompatibleImage(java.awt.image.BufferedImage)
     * @see #createCompatibleImage(java.awt.image.BufferedImage, int, int)
     * @see #createCompatibleImage(int, int)
     * @see #createCompatibleTranslucentImage(int, int)
     * @see #toCompatibleImage(java.awt.image.BufferedImage)
     * @param resource the URL of the picture to load as a compatible image
     * @return a new translucent compatible <code>BufferedImage</code> of the
     *   specified width and height
     * @throws java.io.IOException if the image cannot be read or loaded
     */
    public static BufferedImage loadCompatibleImage(URL resource)
            throws IOException {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(resource);
        return toCompatibleImage(image);
    }

    /**
     * <p>Return a new compatible image that contains a copy of the specified
     * image. This method ensures an image is compatible with the hardware,
     * and therefore optimized for fast blitting operations.</p>
     *
     * @see #createCompatibleImage(java.awt.image.BufferedImage)
     * @see #createCompatibleImage(java.awt.image.BufferedImage, int, int)
     * @see #createCompatibleImage(int, int)
     * @see #createCompatibleTranslucentImage(int, int)
     * @see #loadCompatibleImage(java.net.URL)
     * @param image the image to copy into a new compatible image
     * @return a new compatible copy, with the
     *   same width and height and transparency and content, of <code>image</code>
     */
    public static BufferedImage toCompatibleImage(BufferedImage image) {
        if (image.getColorModel().equals(
                getGraphicsConfiguration().getColorModel())) {
            return image;
        }

        BufferedImage compatibleImage =
                getGraphicsConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(
                    image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),
                    image.getTransparency());
        Graphics g = compatibleImage.getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        g.dispose();

        return compatibleImage;
    }

    /**
     * <p>Returns a thumbnail of a source image. <code>newSize</code> defines
     * the length of the longest dimension of the thumbnail. The other
     * dimension is then computed according to the dimensions ratio of the
     * original picture.</p>
     * <p>This method favors speed over quality. When the new size is less than
     * half the longest dimension of the source image,
     * {@link #createThumbnail(BufferedImage, int)} or
     * {@link #createThumbnail(BufferedImage, int, int)} should be used instead
     * to ensure the quality of the result without sacrificing too much
     * performance.</p>
     *
     * @see #createThumbnailFast(java.awt.image.BufferedImage, int, int)
     * @see #createThumbnail(java.awt.image.BufferedImage, int)
     * @see #createThumbnail(java.awt.image.BufferedImage, int, int)
     * @param image the source image
     * @param newSize the length of the largest dimension of the thumbnail
     * @return a new compatible <code>BufferedImage</code> containing a
     *   thumbnail of <code>image</code>
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if <code>newSize</code> is larger than
     *   the largest dimension of <code>image</code> or &lt;= 0
     */
    public static BufferedImage createThumbnailFast(BufferedImage image,
                                                    int newSize) {
        float ratio;
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();

        if (width > height) {
            if (newSize >= width) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("newSize must be lower than" +
                                                   " the image width");
            } else if (newSize <= 0) {
                 throw new IllegalArgumentException("newSize must" +
                                                    " be greater than 0");
            }

            ratio = (float) width / (float) height;
            width = newSize;
            height = (int) (newSize / ratio);
        } else {
            if (newSize >= height) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("newSize must be lower than" +
                                                   " the image height");
            } else if (newSize <= 0) {
                 throw new IllegalArgumentException("newSize must" +
                                                    " be greater than 0");
            }

            ratio = (float) height / (float) width;
            height = newSize;
            width = (int) (newSize / ratio);
        }

        BufferedImage temp = createCompatibleImage(image, width, height);
        Graphics2D g2 = temp.createGraphics();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                            RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, temp.getWidth(), temp.getHeight(), null);
        g2.dispose();

        return temp;
    }

    /**
     * <p>Returns a thumbnail of a source image.</p>
     * <p>This method favors speed over quality. When the new size is less than
     * half the longest dimension of the source image,
     * {@link #createThumbnail(BufferedImage, int)} or
     * {@link #createThumbnail(BufferedImage, int, int)} should be used instead
     * to ensure the quality of the result without sacrificing too much
     * performance.</p>
     *
     * @see #createThumbnailFast(java.awt.image.BufferedImage, int)
     * @see #createThumbnail(java.awt.image.BufferedImage, int)
     * @see #createThumbnail(java.awt.image.BufferedImage, int, int)
     * @param image the source image
     * @param newWidth the width of the thumbnail
     * @param newHeight the height of the thumbnail
     * @return a new compatible <code>BufferedImage</code> containing a
     *   thumbnail of <code>image</code>
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if <code>newWidth</code> is larger than
     *   the width of <code>image</code> or if code>newHeight</code> is larger
     *   than the height of <code>image</code> or if one of the dimensions
     *   is &lt;= 0
     */
    public static BufferedImage createThumbnailFast(BufferedImage image,
                                                    int newWidth, int newHeight) {
        if (newWidth >= image.getWidth() ||
            newHeight >= image.getHeight()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("newWidth and newHeight cannot" +
                                               " be greater than the image" +
                                               " dimensions");
        } else if (newWidth <= 0 || newHeight <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("newWidth and newHeight must" +
                                               " be greater than 0");
        }

        BufferedImage temp = createCompatibleImage(image, newWidth, newHeight);
        Graphics2D g2 = temp.createGraphics();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                            RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, temp.getWidth(), temp.getHeight(), null);
        g2.dispose();

        return temp;
    }

    /**
     * <p>Returns a thumbnail of a source image. <code>newSize</code> defines
     * the length of the longest dimension of the thumbnail. The other
     * dimension is then computed according to the dimensions ratio of the
     * original picture.</p>
     * <p>This method offers a good trade-off between speed and quality.
     * The result looks better than
     * {@link #createThumbnailFast(java.awt.image.BufferedImage, int)} when
     * the new size is less than half the longest dimension of the source
     * image, yet the rendering speed is almost similar.</p>
     *
     * @see #createThumbnailFast(java.awt.image.BufferedImage, int, int)
     * @see #createThumbnailFast(java.awt.image.BufferedImage, int)
     * @see #createThumbnail(java.awt.image.BufferedImage, int, int)
     * @param image the source image
     * @param newSize the length of the largest dimension of the thumbnail
     * @return a new compatible <code>BufferedImage</code> containing a
     *   thumbnail of <code>image</code>
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if <code>newSize</code> is larger than
     *   the largest dimension of <code>image</code> or &lt;= 0
     */
    public static BufferedImage createThumbnail(BufferedImage image,
                                                int newSize) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();

        boolean isWidthGreater = width > height;

        if (isWidthGreater) {
            if (newSize >= width) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("newSize must be lower than" +
                                                   " the image width");
            }
        } else if (newSize >= height) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("newSize must be lower than" +
                                               " the image height");
        }

        if (newSize <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("newSize must" +
                                               " be greater than 0");
        }

        float ratioWH = (float) width / (float) height;
        float ratioHW = (float) height / (float) width;

        BufferedImage thumb = image;

        do {
            if (isWidthGreater) {
                width /= 2;
                if (width < newSize) {
                    width = newSize;
                }
                height = (int) (width / ratioWH);
            } else {
                height /= 2;
                if (height < newSize) {
                    height = newSize;
                }
                width = (int) (height / ratioHW);
            }


            BufferedImage temp = createCompatibleImage(image, width, height);
            Graphics2D g2 = temp.createGraphics();
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                                RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g2.drawImage(thumb, 0, 0, temp.getWidth(), temp.getHeight(), null);
            g2.dispose();

            thumb = temp;
        } while (newSize != (isWidthGreater ? width : height));

        return thumb;
    }

    /**
     * <p>Returns a thumbnail of a source image.</p>
     * <p>This method offers a good trade-off between speed and quality.
     * The result looks better than
     * {@link #createThumbnailFast(java.awt.image.BufferedImage, int)} when
     * the new size is less than half the longest dimension of the source
     * image, yet the rendering speed is almost similar.</p>
     *
     * @see #createThumbnailFast(java.awt.image.BufferedImage, int)
     * @see #createThumbnailFast(java.awt.image.BufferedImage, int, int)
     * @see #createThumbnail(java.awt.image.BufferedImage, int)
     * @param image the source image
     * @param newWidth the width of the thumbnail
     * @param newHeight the height of the thumbnail
     * @return a new compatible <code>BufferedImage</code> containing a
     *   thumbnail of <code>image</code>
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if <code>newWidth</code> is larger than
     *   the width of <code>image</code> or if code>newHeight</code> is larger
     *   than the height of <code>image or if one the dimensions is not &gt; 0</code>
     */
    public static BufferedImage createThumbnail(BufferedImage image,
                                                int newWidth, int newHeight) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();

        if (newWidth >= width || newHeight >= height) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("newWidth and newHeight cannot" +
                                               " be greater than the image" +
                                               " dimensions");
        } else if (newWidth <= 0 || newHeight <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("newWidth and newHeight must" +
                                               " be greater than 0");
        }

        BufferedImage thumb = image;

        do {
            if (width > newWidth) {
                width /= 2;
                if (width < newWidth) {
                    width = newWidth;
                }
            }

            if (height > newHeight) {
                height /= 2;
                if (height < newHeight) {
                    height = newHeight;
                }
            }

            BufferedImage temp = createCompatibleImage(image, width, height);
            Graphics2D g2 = temp.createGraphics();
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                                RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g2.drawImage(thumb, 0, 0, temp.getWidth(), temp.getHeight(), null);
            g2.dispose();

            thumb = temp;
        } while (width != newWidth || height != newHeight);

        return thumb;
    }

    /**
     * <p>Returns an array of pixels, stored as integers, from a
     * <code>BufferedImage</code>. The pixels are grabbed from a rectangular
     * area defined by a location and two dimensions. Calling this method on
     * an image of type different from <code>BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB</code>
     * and <code>BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB</code> will unmanage the image.</p>
     *
     * @param img the source image
     * @param x the x location at which to start grabbing pixels
     * @param y the y location at which to start grabbing pixels
     * @param w the width of the rectangle of pixels to grab
     * @param h the height of the rectangle of pixels to grab
     * @param pixels a pre-allocated array of pixels of size w*h; can be null
     * @return <code>pixels</code> if non-null, a new array of integers
     *   otherwise
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException is <code>pixels</code> is non-null and
     *   of length &lt; w*h
     */
    public static int[] getPixels(BufferedImage img,
                                  int x, int y, int w, int h, int[] pixels) {
        if (w == 0 || h == 0) {
            return new int[0];
        }

        if (pixels == null) {
            pixels = new int[w * h];
        } else if (pixels.length < w * h) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("pixels array must have a length" +
                                               " >= w*h");
        }

        int imageType = img.getType();
        if (imageType == BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB ||
            imageType == BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB) {
            Raster raster = img.getRaster();
            return (int[]) raster.getDataElements(x, y, w, h, pixels);
        }

        // Unmanages the image
        return img.getRGB(x, y, w, h, pixels, 0, w);
    }

    /**
     * <p>Writes a rectangular area of pixels in the destination
     * <code>BufferedImage</code>. Calling this method on
     * an image of type different from <code>BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB</code>
     * and <code>BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB</code> will unmanage the image.</p>
     *
     * @param img the destination image
     * @param x the x location at which to start storing pixels
     * @param y the y location at which to start storing pixels
     * @param w the width of the rectangle of pixels to store
     * @param h the height of the rectangle of pixels to store
     * @param pixels an array of pixels, stored as integers
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException is <code>pixels</code> is non-null and
     *   of length &lt; w*h
     */
    public static void setPixels(BufferedImage img,
                                 int x, int y, int w, int h, int[] pixels) {
        if (pixels == null || w == 0 || h == 0) {
            return;
        } else if (pixels.length < w * h) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("pixels array must have a length" +
                                               " >= w*h");
        }

        int imageType = img.getType();
        if (imageType == BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB ||
            imageType == BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB) {
            WritableRaster raster = img.getRaster();
            raster.setDataElements(x, y, w, h, pixels);
        } else {
            // Unmanages the image
            img.setRGB(x, y, w, h, pixels, 0, w);
        }
    }
}
```

The code block is really long and I gave it in case anyone needs it, but most of the operation is really done towards the top in the first 54 lines.

Anyways, the problem is that the transparent image is being drawn to the form and I see a transparent form, like the one below:

[image]

But, the JPanel is not showing up. I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `Well, don't get annoyed by me if I ask stupid questions since I am not a pro` - Yes I will get annoyed with you when you continue to waste our time. You completely ignored the advice given to you in your last question which is why you are back asking another question again wasting our time or the time of other people who read the question. Not only that you didn't even bother to accept an answer from the last question although both answer addressed your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very good reason why (we have repeatdly) advised you not to override `paint`, especially on a top level container!

As I suggested in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15982431/java-swing-transparent-png-permanently-captures-original-background/15983717#15983717) (and got scolded for because you failed to provide full context ;))

`paint` is responsible for calling `paintChildren`, which, oddly, paints all the child components.  Now that you've failed to call `super.paint` nothing is getting painted.

The problem you have is that there is no where on a top level container you can actually paint under the children.

Instead, you should create yourself a custom component, such as a `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method and render the image there.  Then add you components to it.

Don't forget to call `super.paintComponent`

**Update with links**

Make sure you have a read through [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details

**Updated with example**

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TransparentWindow01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TransparentWindow01();
    }

    public TransparentWindow01() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
//                Java 6...
//                AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(frame, true);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage image;

        public TestPane() {

            try {
                image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/5UNGbsr.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
            setOpaque(false);

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            });

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(new JLabel("Look Ma, no hands!"));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            Dimension size = image == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
            System.out.println(size);
            return size;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (image != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                int x = (getWidth() - image.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - image.getHeight()) / 2;
                g2d.drawImage(image, x, y, this);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. Well, don't get annoyed by me if I ask stupid questions since I am not a pro in Java yet. I want to convert the whole "form" into a transparent png and all controls should appear on top of this png. Will going with your JPanel route achieve this?

Comment: @DemCodeLines Yes.  The second example (from my previous answer) will do this for

Comment: @DemCodeLines Also beware, `JWindow` does strange things to focusable controls (you basically can't get them to grab focus for some reason), you're better off using a undecoreated `JFrame` - just beware ;)

Comment: There are any number of ways you can acheieve this.  You could use [`Image#getScaledInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance%28int,%20int,%20int%29), you could use an [`AffineTransform`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) or you could use a [custom solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928).  Each one one has it's merits and draw backs

Comment: @camickr I still could have been wrong, but I read "splash screen" which suggested other wise.  Your points are still valid and I agree with them totally ;)